# bit reset in a block of memory

Tags: c, logic, bit-manipulation

I have a block of memory allocated 20bytes(160-bits) with memset value of 1. Each bit represents an incoming data, if the data is received the bit is set else reset. I have initially set all the 160-bits and I will reset if the data is not received. Below is the sample code:

```
char *buf = malloc(20);
memset(buf,1,20);

recvfun() {
static int index;
index++;
   if(!received)
     *buf = *buf ^ (1<<(160-index));
...
}
```

I think *buf will give only 8-bits, not the complete memory block, so everytime I try to reset the bit, the above code only resets in the first 8-bits. If suppose a 99th data is not received I need to reset 99th bit. Can you please help me in achieving this. thanks for your valuable time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to break it down into a byte index and a bit index, e.g. change:

```
if(!received)
  *buf = *buf ^ (1<<(160-index));
```

to:

```
if (!received)
{
    const int byte_index = index / CHAR_BIT;
    const int bit_index = index & (1 << CHAR_BIT - 1);
    buf[byte_index] ^= (1 << bit_index);
}
```

Note also that `memset(buf,1,20);` in your code above should be `memset(buf,255,20);` if you want to initialise all bits to 1.

Answer (score 3):

You need to calculated two things:

- index in the block
- bit-offset

The code to calculate it is quite straightforward:

```
blockindex = index / 8;
offset     = index % 8;
```

Then just set the bit by combining the index and the offset:

```
buf[blockindex] ^= 1 << offset;
```

**EDIT:** Although my answer uses the same principle as the one of Paul R, Paul's answer is technically better because he uses the correct constants (CHAR_BIT) instead of hardcoding 8 (shame on me).